# In Eclipse, Is there a way to change the 15 character limit on the open file names displayed in the editor tabs?

Tags: eclipse

The source code I'm working with has many files where the first 15 characters of a file name are the same. When multiple files are open in Eclipse the tabs all look the same. I have searched online and not come up with any answers, including a vague reference on this site, where someone asked a similar question, but the suggestions more had to do with configuring the number of tabs, not the number of characters in the file name appearing on the tab.

As far as I can tell, the ability to configure this does not seem to appear in Preferences for Eclipse; but then again, I'm relatively new to it. I would like to have wider tabs, displaying the unique portion of the file name.

Comment: Why are they named like that? And is Ctrl/Cmd+E a usable workaround?

Comment: do the refactoring magic on that sh*t, `max 15 char class names` is good coding practice... not 65535 just because you can!

Comment: buy a widescreen 100 inch, can you tell me how you would fit all open tabs and still show the filename that are more than 15 chars long? No, this is not possible. Either you have a widescreen and can see maybe 5 open tabs with fullname. Or you limit the open files settings. Preferences -> Editors -> Close Editors automatically and set that value to 4 or something that fits your screen.

Comment: As noted below, the value seems to be hard coded. It does not matter how few tabs you have open or how wide your screen is. The file name width on the tab is 15 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this can't be changed using a preference.

The width seems to be hard coded in the stack rendering code (`org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.sw.StackRenderer`) so it would require a custom renderer to change.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for some sort of hidden magic....Frustrating, as its kind of odd to name files that way in the first place, but when you are working in someone else's code you don't have a choice.